# Update database without migration in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I've created an ASP.NET MVC sample application in Visual Studio. I added two classes like below :

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }
}
```

and then I added two `DbSet` to the main `DbContext` like this:

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public IDbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

But now when I run project, I get this error :

> The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created

I just wanted to know is there a way to update the database without using migrations (`Add-migrations` and `update-database`)?

Comment: i think you're looking for DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges

Comment: You can use a [database initializer](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx) as Rise suggests. These are handy for early development and have their own seed methods. Once you get non-seed data you want to preserve you can switch to migrations. Using a null initializer won't create the database objects - it will assume the code model matches the database (dangerous).

Comment: You can delete the `dbo.__MigrationHistory` and try. Please see my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/67821254/3057246

Answer (score 6):

You can update the database structure in the way you want (queries, via DBMS user interface and so on).
If you do so you need to disable configuration check.

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourContext>(null);
```

(I insert this in a static constructor in the context)

Answer (score 4):

You can enable automatic migrations to achieve this. This approach definitely uses code-first migration but you don't need to use *Add-Migration* command or *update-database*.

Run **Enable-Migrations –EnableAutomaticMigrations** from package manager console first to generates a Configuration class as follows:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ApplicationDbContext>
{
  public Configuration()
  {
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
  }

  protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
  { 
  }
}
```

Now you could either update the db context's constructor to migrate to latest version as follows:

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
    : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
{
   Database.SetInitializer(
             new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, Configuration>());
   this.Database.Initialize(true);
}
```

Or migrate to the latest version on application start up as follows:

```
using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
 {
    Database.SetInitializer(
              new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, Configuration>());
    context.Database.Initialize(true);
 }
```

***UPDATE***

If you prefer not to use migrations at all, you may consider setting the database initializer to null and handle the db migration manually using scripts

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourContext>(null);
```

Comment: The answer to "Update database __without migration__" is to run `–EnableAutomaticMigrations`?!?!

Comment: "I just wanted to know is there a way to update the database without using migrations (Add-migrations and update-database)?" - this question gave me a notion that the OP wanted to get it done without handling the migration manually..and moreover there was no mention that the OP wanted to take care of migration manually using scripts..anyways, i have updated the answer..thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 2):

With EF6:

I think what you can do it to have the `Database.SetInitializer` in your `DbContext` Class constructor to have the database created on the first run. This I guess you already have, next you can comment it where it says `Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyContext>());`

and delete the `dbo.__MigrationHistory` table created in your database.

Now you can use `Alter Table..` to add remove columns in your database table then in your `C# Table class` to match.